# How to write zip file into httpresponse

Tags: java, jquery, http-headers, zip

I have created the zip file (sample.zip) which has some files with no issues. When I open the sample.zip, it contains the file which expected.

I want to put that zip file into http response. Currently I am using the following:

```
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+"sampleZip.zip");
        response.setContentLength(2048);
        response.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "fileDownload=true; path=/");
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("sample.zip");
        OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int bytes;
        while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }
        response.flushBuffer();
```

Now its download the zip file in my browser default download location. But when I open that zip file it showing

> Cannot open file: it does not appear to be valid archive

Kindly help me to fix this please.

Comment: try setting the content-type to application/x-zip-compressed and see if it works

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis : can you please update the piece of code of writing the bytes please

Comment: Well you're copying a single byte at a time, which is far from efficient... but it should do the copy correctly.

Comment: The content length you're specifying, is it a constant: are you sure that's the size of the zip file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code looks good to me. But you are setting a default content length which might be the issue. Create File instanceand use the file.length() method to set the content length ans use the same file for your input stream. Also reading byte by byte is not a good idea. If possible use apache's IOUtils.copy() to copy data from your input stream to the ServletOutputStream.